# Can't understand: if (val == null ? it.next() == null : val.equals(it.next()))

Tags: java, iterator, listiterator

I saw this code snippet on [Java Tutorial Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html), however, no matter how hard I have tried, I can't understand the `if (val == null ? it.next() == null : val.equals(it.next()))`.

What is its function and how does it work?

```
public static <E> void replace(List<E> list, E val, E newVal) {
    for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (val == null ? it.next() == null : val.equals(it.next()))
            it.set(newVal);
}
```

Comment: it is ternary operation its skeleton is if(condition)?operation1:operation2; if condition is true it chooses operation1 else 2.Speaking it is simple if else code in one line here is blog which explain in detail.http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Comment: Although it's legal Java (it compiles), too bad it appears in TUTORIAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is equality check between `val` and `it.next()`. `null.equals()` will throw `NullPointerException`, so the condition is used to avoid that.

```
if ( // the if statement
    val == null ? // let me name this "condition A"
        it.next() == null : // this will be evaluated if condition A is true
        val.equals(it.next()) // this will be evaluated if condition A is false
) // the if statement
```

Answer (score -1):

This code tries to find `val` in your list and then replaces it with `newVal`

```
for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext();)
        if (val == null && it.next() == null)
        { }
        else if val.equals(it.next()))
            it.set(newVal);
```

Comment: 1. This code may call `it.next()` twice in one loop. 2. This code won't call `it.set(newVal);` when both `val` and `it.next()` are `null`, while the original code will.